# Why variable passed into block is not dealloced?

Tags: objective-c

I have tested following code.

```
// Employee.h

@interface Employee : NSObject
@property(nonatomatic, copy) void (^print)(void);
@end

// Employee.m

@implementation Employee
@synthesize print = _print;

- (void)dealloc {
    [_print release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

// main.m

int main() {

    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Employee* john = [[[Employee alloc] init] autorelease];

    john.print = ^{
        NSLog(@"block test %@", john);
    };

    [pool drain];
}
```

In this case, variable "john"'s dealloc is not called.
But if I don't log john variable(Just like as NSLog(@"block test")), then it's dealloc is called.
What would be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's circular reference, which will prevent the affected instance to be deallocated in the system of reference-count memory management.

According to the documentation

> In a manually reference-counted environment, local variables used
>   within the block are retained when the block is copied.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW3

`john` got retained when the block is copied to `print`, so it's like that `john` has retained itself via `print` variable. Even `john` will be released by the pool's draining, the reference count would never reach zero and `dealloc` would never get called.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question. when john.print is executed, john is retained?

Comment: @Daoxin the time `john` got automatically retained is at the line the property `print` is assigned. Compiler automatically do this to make sure that `john` would not get deallocated before the execution of the code in the block, which might be sometime later e.g. in case of asynchronous callback block.

Answer (score 0):

As tia said, you have a retain cycle here.

Here is the solution to get rid of it:

```
int main() {

    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Employee* john = [[[Employee alloc] init] autorelease];

    Employee* __weak weakjohn = john; // weak reference to john, to be used in the block.
    john.print = ^{
        NSLog(@"block test %@", weakjohn);
    };

    [pool drain];
}
```